# How can I replace the roller mechanism on this door?

Tags: doors

I have a cupboard in my kitchen that has a roller front door. A few months ago the roller mechanism broke. I need an inexpensive solution for replacing it. I have looked around but can't find a suitable replacement anywhere. It seems like most roller doors are large industrial ones. Has anyone got any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Are there any markings on the door to identify the manufacturer? I am also trying to find such a door.

Answer (score 1):

Ikea makes a roll front door [cabinet](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00158439/).  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it may be a start...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try either the local hardware store or a glass repair specialty store and ask to look at glass shower door rollers. They come in several widths and diameters. They may have something that will fit.